# Type name as a string

Tags: c++

I posted [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59510478/10147399) answer recently. OP in the StackOverflow question mentioned that it was for educational use, but I can imagine it being used as a debugging aid. Then I decided to improve it slightly and make it a compile-time function. Code:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <string_view>
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>

#ifndef __GNUC__
static_assert(false, "GCC specific");
#endif // !__GNUC__

// Finds a character in a nul terminated string.
// Returns the last character if sought one isn't found.
// Notes:
// 1. Using this because std::strchr isn't constexpr.
// `PChr` is a separate typename instead of just using Chr* to allow `Chr*` and
// `Chr const*` as the pointer.
// 2. pstr shall not be nullptr.
template <typename PChr, typename Chr>
[[gnu::pure, gnu::nonnull, gnu::returns_nonnull, nodiscard]]
static constexpr auto*
constexpr_strchr(PChr pstr, Chr const value) noexcept {
    // PChr must be a raw pointer type because of gnu::nonnull and
    // gnu::returns_nonnull
    static_assert(std::is_pointer_v<PChr>, "PChr must be a raw pointer type");
    auto constexpr nul = Chr{};
    while (*pstr != value && *pstr != nul) {
        ++pstr;
    }
    return pstr;
}

// Returns distance from ptr to the end of the array.
// Notes:
// 1. ptr shall not be nullptr
// 2. ptr shall be inside the array (arr)
template <typename T, auto size>
[[gnu::const, gnu::artificial, gnu::nonnull, gnu::always_inline, nodiscard]]
inline static constexpr auto
distance_to_end(const T (&arr)[size], T const* const ptr) noexcept {
    return arr + size - ptr;
}

// Returns type T as a string_view.
// Ex: std::string -> "std::string"
template <typename T>
[[gnu::const, nodiscard]]
static constexpr auto type_name_finder() noexcept {
    // __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ means "$FUNCTION_SIGNATURE [with T = $TYPE]".

    // +2 here to skip "= "
    auto const* const begin = constexpr_strchr(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__, '=') + 2;

    // -2 meaning up to "]\0"
    auto const size =
            static_cast<std::size_t>(distance_to_end(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__, begin) - 2);
    return std::string_view{begin, size};
}

// Inline string_view with the type name.
template <typename T>
inline constexpr auto type_name = type_name_finder<T>();


// Example Class
template <typename T1, typename T2>
class my_class {};

int main() {
    // Example use-case
    my_class<int&, std::vector<double>> my_arr[20];
    std::cout << type_name<decltype(my_arr)>;
}
```

Code uses `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` in GCC and Clang to get a variable's type as a string. I would appreciate any comments on correctness and readability. I used a lot of GCC specific attributes, because `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` is GCC specific and for this reason the code can't be portable anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to reinvent the wheel... This specific challenge was discussed in answers to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/81870/1593077): Read [HowardHinnant's long answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20170989/1593077), then read the final, pretty, `constexpr` answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56766138/1593077).  @Snowhawk quoted the code there - now you have some references and the build-up to the final form of the code.

Comment: I should have looked around before spending time on this thing.

Answer (score 4):

```
    // __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ means "$FUNCTION_SIGNATURE [with T = $TYPE]".
```

When you call `type_name_finder()`, the only part that changes in `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` is `$TYPE`. We can use this information to strip the static decoration surrounding that type.

```
template <typename T>
static constexpr auto type_name_finder() {
    std::string_view name, prefix, suffix;

#if defined(__clang__)
    name = __PRETTY_FUNCTION__;
    prefix = "auto type_name_finder() [T = ";
    suffix = "]";
#elif defined(__GNUC__)
    name = __PRETTY_FUNCTION__;
    prefix = "constexpr auto type_name_finder() [with T = ";
    suffix = "]";
#endif

    name.remove_prefix(prefix.size());
    name.remove_suffix(suffix.size());
    return name;
}
```

Comment: MSVC version won't work properly because for built in types `auto __cdecl type_name_finder<class` does not have the "class" word.

Comment: `std::string_view::remove_prefix` is not `noexcept`. I don't think it's very appropriate to mark `type_name_finder` not-throwing.

Comment: Besides that, your implementation is great (+1). Thanks for this much improved version!

Comment: And what if the actual prefix or suffix isn't the one you expect? To me it looks like undefined behavior then.